# Зависимые списки Не послылает зависимость

Tags: php, jquery

```
$('#selectTerritory').change(function(){
    var selectTerritory= $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: "registration.php",
        data: {Territory:selectTerritory},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#detale_sitis').html(data);
        }
    });
});

$('#selectRayons').change(function () {
    var selectRayons = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "registration.php",
        data: {Rayons: selectRayons},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#detale_rayons').html(data);
        }
    });
}); 


echo "<select id='selectRayons'  name='Rayons'>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value=".$row['ter_name'].">".$row['ter_name']."</option>";
} ;
echo "</select>";

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

echo "<select id='selectTowns'  name='Towns'>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value=".$row['ter_type_id'].">".$row['ter_name']."</option>";
} ;
echo "</select>";

echo "<br>";
```

`$_POST['Rayons']` почему то пуст.

Вопрос: почему?

Как правильно было бы закодить ajax запрос, дайте ссылку или опишите наглядно. Спасибо ребята.

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть Rayons в кавычки `data: {"Rayons": selectRayons},`

Comment: Не поголо, проблема не в этом.

Comment: Вопрос следующего характера, если страничка загрузилась и построен DOM объект сайта, то получается после echo уже ничего нельза что ли менять??

Comment: Менять дальше уже будите на стороне клиента с использованием js, так как сервер данные клиенту отдал.

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо сериализовать данные, и уже в таком виде отправлять.

```js
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $("#hold").html($("#test").find("select").serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <select name="territory">
    <option value="1">Опция1</option>
    <option value="2">Опция2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br>

<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Serialize div" />
<p id="hold" style="border: 1px solid red">Сериализованные данные</p>
```

### В дополнении

От себя добавлю, старайтесь особо не мешать PHP с вёрсткой.
Либо одно, либо другое, если уж прям нужно то делайте так:

```
<select id="selectRayons"  name="Rayons">
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['ter_name']; ?>">
            <?= $row['ter_name']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>

<br>

<select id="selectTowns"  name="Towns">
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['ter_name']; ?>">
            <?= $row['ter_name']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>

<br>
```

Comment: Дело не в сериализации а скорее в том что после одного аякс запроса, заполнился див, и в уже заполненный див нужно обратиться для следующего аякс запроса.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман не совсем понимаю, что у вас где уже заполнилось. И какие ajax запросы уже сработали.